# How can I download the images from a website to a google drive folder using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping

I would like to download images from the web to a drive folder just by writing the image link.
for example I want to download the image is in a drive folder automatically with google apps script.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhw9C.jpg

It would be like a kind of web scraping in which I get the images of said web in a folder.

```
function myFunction() {
  
    var destination_id = '1cgzNUb88ZHXSQ7iZ0zYigH1f7KD_7geH' //// Id of the folder in which we are going to store the image
    
     var img = ...;
    
    
     var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id)
    
     destination.createFile(img)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, I think that the image can be retrieved using UrlFetchApp. So in the case of your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var img = ...;
```

#### To:

```
var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://i.imgur.com/QCFXhpg.jpg").getBlob();
```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your help was very useful.

Comment: How can I download a folder to drive using GAS?

Comment: @perico palote Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I think that the situation of your comment is new question, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do this?